# Abort / quit / return macro in RPM

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, abort

I’m writting a RPM. In the `%prep` section, I test the presence of a FS and its size. If incorrect, I want the RPM to quit. I found the `%{error:"Oops dat failed!}` macro but it actually just prints on stderr and doesn’t abort anyways.

Do you have any idea or hint?

Answer (score 2):

You want it in the `%pre` section, not `%prep` section. Then just exit that mini-script non-zero and the RPM won't install.

The `%prep` section is only used when building the RPM itself, not installing it.